How to copy surface polygons from 3D model to 3D polygon layer?
I am using ArcScene 10.4.1 with 3D analyst, network analyst and spatial analysit extensions to create routable 3D building model explained here.

I could create points and lines as illustrated above, and now trying to make polygons to show room layout. I have created 3D model in SketchUp and imported it into ArcScene via Import 3D Files tool. It is nice if I can copy and paste floor polygons to polygon layer, but geometry type of the imported 3D building model is a single MultiPatch and it is not editable. 3D editor can move and rotate the entire model but each part is not selectable.
I tried to convert it into singlepart polygons via several tools such as multipart to singleparts, Feature Class to Shapefile, etc., but they did not work.
Any suggestions to copy polygons from an imported 3D model to a polygon layer?
